# Deploy Spring Boot with Gradle (Kotlin) application - the jar is not found

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, gradle, kotlin

I have a simple app made in Spring Boot, Kotlin, Gradle. I followed [the official tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku) and tried to follow all the possible defaults.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 231 bytes | 231.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> JVM Common app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 50.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v50
remote:        https://---.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

It's weird that I get "JVM Common app detected" instead of "Gradle app detected".

I can't deploy the app. When I do `heroku logs --tail`, I get:

```
2018-04-02T23:02:39.257887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=50478 -jar build/libs/scraper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2018-04-02T23:02:41.645544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-04-02T23:02:41.664910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-04-02T23:02:41.577966+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/scraper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2018-04-02T23:02:41.572483+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-04-02T23:05:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ---
2018-04-02T23:05:21.108667+00:00 app[api]: Release v50 created by user ---
2018-04-02T23:05:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-02T23:05:21.635834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
```

- Using Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE
- Using Kotlin 1.2.31
- no special tasks in `build.gradle`
- no `Procfile`

Is there any way to fix this using the defaults (i.e.. no Procfile, no special Gradle tasks)? If not possible using defaults, what can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed be getting (at least) the following:

```
remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Spring Boot detected
```

Is this the first push you did? Did you set a buildpack manually? Perhaps try clearing the buildpacks (heroku buildpacks:clear). If you can publish your app somewhere, it might help to check what the issue could be.